# Reboot into `initramfs` after altering partition table

Tags: filesystems, partition, fstab, initramfs, partition-table

### Problem Overview

I recently upgraded my remote server contract with IONOS, increasing my hard drive space from 8GB to 80GB. I have an Ubuntu OS running bash.

I then went about extending my working partition, following a tutorial here:
https://www.ryadel.com/en/resize-extend-disk-partition-unallocated-disk-space-linux-centos-rhel-ubuntu-debian/

All was OK, I wrote a new partition map, then rebooted my system. I waited a minute or two and then attempted to `ssh` into my server as usual. Problem. My ssh connection hangs, until eventually exiting with a `time out`.

### Solution Attempts

At first, I reasoned the process of rebooting after a partition map change may take some time, and this was the cause of the timeout. After several more `ssh` attempts, this did not seem likely.

I used a 'KVM Console' provided in my IONOS console - here, the shell is in a state of `(initramfs)`.

In attempting to diagnose the issue, I have tried the following:

1. Running: `fsck /dev/sda1`
   Result: `/dev/sda1: clean, 312/124672 files, 26890/124672 blocks`
2. Running: `fsck /dev/sda1`
   Result: `fsck: error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /dev/sda2`
3. Running: `blkid`
   Result:

`/dev/sda1: UUID="longString" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="520f1760-01"`

`/dev/sda2: PARTUUID="520f1760-02"`

4. Running all of the following commands returns `sh: command name: not found`. These are:

- vgdisplay -v vg00
- parted -l /dev/sda
- free -m
- cfdisk
- lvdisplay -v
- fdisk /dev/sda
- pvresize /dev/sda2

5. The output of `cat proc/partitions` is:

```
major minor #blocks name
8 0 83886080 sda
8 1 498688 sda1
8 2 83386368 sda2
11 0 1048575 sr0
```

From the above, I am confused why (2) returns `no such file or directory` - the entry `sda2` is listed under the directory `dev`.

6. The output of `cat /proc/cmdline` is:
   `BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-132-generic root=/dev/mapper/vg00-lv01 ro apparmor=0`
7. After entering `lvm` and then `vgscan -ccc`, the output is:

```
....
Start of output not visible in terminal window due to no scrolling
....
filter caching bad /dev/loop5
Opened /dev/loop6 RO O_DIRECT
/dev/loop6: size is 0 sectors
Closed /dev/loop6
/dev/loop6: Skipping: Too small to hold a PV
filter caching bad /dev/loop6
Opended /dev/loop7 RO O_DIRECT
/dev/loop7: size is 0 sectors
Closed /dev/loop7
/dev/loop7: Skipping: Too small to hold a PV
filter caching bad /dev/loop7
Will scan 3 devices skip 0
Checking fd limit for num_devs 3 want 35 soft 1024 hard 4096
Scanning 3 devices for VG info
Scanning submitted 3 reads
Processing data from device /dev/sda 8:0 fd 4 block 0x55b511a17cd0
Scan filtering /dev/sda
/dev/sda: using cached size 167772160 sectors
/dev/sda: Skipping: Partition table signature found
filter caching bad /dev/sda
/dev/sda: Not processing filtered
Processing data from device /dev/sda1 8:1 fd 5 block 0x55b511a17d10
Scan filtering /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: using cached size 997376 sectors
/dev/sda1: Device is a partition, using primary device sda for mpath component detection
/dev/sda1: using cached size 997376 sectors
filter caching good /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: No lvm label detected
Processing data from device /dev/sda2 8:2 fd 6 block 0x55b511a17d50
Scan filtering /dev/sda2
/dev/sda2: using cached size 166772736 sectors
/dev/sda2: Device is a partition, using primary device sda for mpath component detection
/dev/sda2: using cached size 166772736 sectors
filter caching good /dev/sda2
Label checksum incorrect on /dev/sda2 - ignoring
/dev/sda2: No lvm label detected
Scanned devices: read errors 0 process errors 0 failed 0
Found VG info for 0 VGs
Obtaining the complete list of VGs to process
No volume groups found
Unlocking /run/lock/lvm/P_global
_undo_flock /run/lock/lvm/P_global
Dropping VG info
lvmcache has no info for vgname "#orphans_lvm2" with VGID #orphans_lvm2.
lvmcache has no info for vgname "#orphans_lvm2".
lvmcache: Initialised VG #orphans_lvm2.
Completed: vgscan -vvv
```

8. The directory `/etc/lvm/backup` exists and contains:
   `vg00`
   The directory `/etc/lvm/archive` exists and contains:
   `vg00_00000-1647277590.vg vg00_00001-1228658393.vg`

(3) and (5) give me hope - the location seems to be recognised, what would this suggest ?

### Specific Steps Before Reboot

In summary, the steps I took before rebooting my system were:

1. ran `fdisk /dev/sda` and noted the start and end points of the file systems by entering `p`.
2. Deleted the file system map by entering `d` and then selecting `sda2` with `2`
3. Created a new partition map by entering `n`. Setting the partition type to `primary`.
4. I then entered the start and end locations for the new partition, as noted in step (1).
5. I changed the partition type, by entering `t`, and selecting the 2nd partition by entering `2`.
6. I specified the partition type to be 'Linux LVM' by entering the HEX code `8e`.
7. Before writing to the disk, I ensured start and end points were correctly listed by entering `p`. The start point matched that of the original partition. The end point matched that of the disk end point.
8. I wrote the partition map to disk by entering `w`.
9. I reboot the system with `reboot`.

The result of running `lvm p` prior to partition map changes was:

[image: lvm p output]

At this point I am not sure how to proceed - I have encountered a file system issue before and was troubled at the prospect of loosing all my files. Ultimately, in that case, the files were still present. From that experience I am restraining my assumption all is lost.

Does anyone have any suggestions, or tips to offer in terms of debugging this situation ? Please feel free to ask if you would like extra information regarding my setup.

### Update

I have been able to boot into a knoppix CD on my remote server. Here, I have run `fdisk -l` which outputs:

```
Disk /dev/ram0: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/cloop0: 1.83 GiB, 1960312832 bytes, 3828736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/cloop1: 9.63 GiB, 10335027200 bytes, 20185600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/zram0: 1.45 GiB, 1560817664 bytes, 381059 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 80 GiB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x520f1760

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    999423    997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       999424 167772159 166772736 79.5G 8e Linux LVM
```

I feel the final output lines, displaying the partition map for `sda1` and `sda2`, are of interest. I believe the type of `sda2` is correct as `8e` (a Linux LVM), and the `Start` value correctly falls after the `End` of `sda1`.

### Update II

Before attempting the below steps, I created a snapshot for backing up the system to its current state. I have now returned to this snapshot.

Attempting to restore from the `/etc/lvm/backup/vg00` file (initramfs), first I ran `pvcreate --restorefile /etc/lvm/backup/vg00 --uuid R5VWXg-jamB-5dWM-PpwY-7a49-LRz7-Vrvdl2 /dev/sda2`. This returned:

```
WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid `R5VWXg-jamB-5dWM-PpwY-7a49-LRz7-Vrvdl2. 
Failed to clear hint file.
Physical volume "/dev/sda2" successfully created.
```

Then, I ran `vgcfgrestore --file /etc/lvm/backup/vg00` which returned:

```
No command with matching syntax recognised.
Nearest similar syntax command has syntax:
vgfcgrestore -f:--file String VG
Restore VG metadata from specified file.
```

There seems to be an issue here.

Comment: `cat /proc/partitions`? `lvm vgs`? boot a rescue system and check / chroot from there?

Comment: I have added the output of `cat /proc/partitions` to my question. Entering `lvm vgs` returns nothing. Booting into recovery mode prints `Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... Volume group "vg00" not found Cannot process volume group vg00` followed by ` Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device`. I am then returned to the `(initramfs)` shell - do you suggest I can chroot from here ?

Comment: not familiar with ionos - does your hoster not offer a rescue system for servers? you should check if the partition offset is really correct, or the partition got wiped, or what. `hexdump -C /dev/sda2 | less` and see if you find LVM metadata (ascii). but it's tiresome to do this with initramfs shell, so a proper rescue system would be good

Comment: Try `lvm vgscan`, then `lvm pvs`. It should show `sda2` as a LVM physical volume - if not, you could read `dmesg | less` to see if there are any error messages about partition `sda2`. You might also try `lvm vgscan -vvv`, but be warned: the output will be quite long. If you can capture it and put it into an accessible pastebin somewhere, that would be great.

Comment: @frostschutz reading on the IONOS site, it seems they offer 'Dedicated Servers' with the ability to boot into a rescue system but for my product, a 'Virtual Private Server' it seems I need to contact customer support and have them boot the system into what they refer to as 'Repair Mode'. I am waiting to get through to customer service and will update when I make it through.

Unfortunately (initramfs) does not feature `hexdump` or `less`.

Comment: @telcoM thankyou for your reply - After entering `lvm`, when I try any of the commands you suggest, noting is returned (the same result as hitting 'enter'). `dmesg` provides output but it is indeed long, and there doesn't seem to be a means of scrolling up in the terminal. `less` is not recognised by (initramfs).

The output of `vgscan -vvv` gives clues. I have added the output in an edit above.

Comment: `Label checksum incorrect on /dev/sda2 - ignoring` suggests the LVM label on `sda2` has been damaged. Ouch. Does the `/etc/lvm/backup` or `/etc/lvm/archive/` directory exist within the initramfs, and does either of them have any files in it?

Comment: Both `/etc/lvm/backup` and `/etc/lvm/archive` exist, and contain several files - I have added their contents to the above post.

Comment: @frostschutz I have been able to boot into a `knoppix` OS instance from a CD on my remote server - allowing me a full shell for debugging. The output of `hexdump -C /dev/sda2 | less` is an 8 character HEX string, 2 sets of 8 colums each with 2 character HEX strings, and finally 16 ASCII characters encased in `|` characters.

The ASCII characters look promising: they begin with `LABELONE........`, further down there is a line beginning with `vg00` - what would you recommend I search for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should examine the LVM VG metadata backup file `/etc/lvm/backup/vg00`  and find the original PV UUID of `/dev/sda2` from there. It is a text file, and the PV UUID should be in a location like this: (`[...]` indicates some lines omitted for brevity)

```
[...]
vg00 {
    [...]
    physical_volumes {
    
        pv0 {
            id = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx"
            device = "/dev/sda2"   # Hint only
```

Once you know the PV UUID, you can use the backup file and the UUID to restore the PV UUID like this: (commands prefixed with `lvm` for use in initramfs environment; if you have extracted the VG metadata backup file from initramfs and do this in Knoppix, you can omit the `lvm` prefixes)

```
lvm pvcreate --restorefile /etc/lvm/backup/vg00 --uuid xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx /dev/sda2
```

Once the PV UUID is restored, you can restore the rest of VG metadata with:

```
lvm vgcfgrestore --file /etc/lvm/backup/vg00 vg00
```

After this, the VG should be good for activation:

```
lvm vgchange -ay vg00
```

If the VG activates successfully, and the filesystem within it can be mounted (with e.g. `mount /dev/mapper/vg00-lvol1 /mnt`), you should now be able to boot normally.

Once the system is running normally, you'll need two commands as root to achieve your original goal:

```
pvresize /dev/sda2
```

After this, `pvs` should indicate the `sda2` PV is now successfully resized and `vgs` should indicate there is now plenty of unallocated space in `vg00`. To finally make use of it:

```
lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/vg00-lvol1
```

and now `df` should indicate the root filesystem has plenty of free space again.

---

There is the command `growpart` (part of the `cloud-guest-utils` package in Debian, might be packaged separately as `cloud-utils-growpart` or just `growpart` in other distributions) which is specifically made to extend partitions safely and quickly, usually with no rebooting required.

In this specific case, the extension could have been achieved with just three commands:

```
growpart /dev/sda 2
pvresize /dev/sda2
lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/vg00-lvol1
```

Comment: Amazing - thankyou for the direction. I have found the PV UUID of sda2. I have followed the steps you list above and have added their result to my post above.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like `vgcfgrestore` needs the name of the VG to restore in addition to the backup file. Edited.

Comment: Absolute legend - boot successful and, following your tips on resizing the partition, the full 80GB is now in use! Many thanks

Comment: Now just wait a day or two (in case others have something to fill in), then click on the hollow green checkmark next to the beginning of the answer to mark it as the accepted answer if you're happy with it. When restoring corrupted LVM metadata from backups, the use of `pvcreate` first is a bit un-intuitive, but it's described in the `vgcfgrestore` man page, if you read it carefully.